# Picture doesn't display in react native (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I just have started to learn `React Native`, and I'm following [official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html#content), both in my emulator and phone (Android), image doesn't appear, just empty white screen. So my question, why it doesn't displayed on the screen? P.S: internet connection works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';

    class Bananas extends Component {
      render() {
        let pic = {
          uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
        };
        return (
          <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
        );
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('Bananas', () => Bananas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the Image part correctly, I believe you just need to wrap it in a view.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View } from 'react-native';

class Bananas extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
        <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Bananas', () => Bananas);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! it seems that there should be added import of the View, in that case!